# 'less' the file specified by the output of 'which'

Tags: linux, command-line

command 'which' shows the link to a command.
command 'less' open the file.

How can I 'less' the file as the output of 'which'?
I don't want to use two commands like below to do it.

```
=>which script
/file/to/script/fiel
=>less /file/to/script/fiel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use case for [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
less -- "$(which commandname)"
```

That said, if your shell is bash, consider using `type -P` instead, which (unlike the external command `which`) is built into the shell:

```
less -- "$(type -P commandname)"
```

Note the quotes: These are important for reliable operation. Without them, the command may not work correctly if the filename contains characters inside IFS (by default, whitespace) or can be evaluated as a glob expression.

The double dashes are likewise there for correctness: Any argument after them is treated as positional (as per [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02)), so even if a filename starting with a dash were to be returned (however unlikely this may be), it ensures that `less` treats that as a filename rather than as the beginning of a sequence of options or flags.

---

You may also wish to consider honoring the user's pager selection via the environment variable `$PAGER`, and using `type` without `-P` to look for aliases, shell functions and builtins:

```
cmdsource() {
  local sourcefile
  if sourcefile="$(type -P -- "$1")"; then
    "${PAGER:-less}" -- "$sourcefile"
  else
    echo "Unable to find source for $1" >&2
    echo "...checking for a shell builtin:" >&2
    type -- "$1"
  fi
}
```

This defines a function you can run:

```
cmdsource commandname
```

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to just pipe it over, try this:

```
which script | less
```

Comment: That will just show you the filename, not the file contents